# Wix: Creating Bootstrap .exe for .msp causes original version to uninstall

Tags: wix

I am trying to create a Wix Bootstrap executable that contains an .msp patch file. I have generated the patch file using pyro.exe and the patch itself works absolutely fine and updates the required files correctly when ran by itself.

However we package all our .msi's in a Wix Bootstrap project with a custom user interface, which I have cloned for the patch files. However when running the executable this way it removes all the files from the install directory.

Has anyone experienced this issue before or am I doing something wrong? Thank you in advance, let me know if you need further code examples.

BootstrapBundle.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
 xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
 xmlns:vi="http://schemas.visualinstaller.de/VisualInstallerWixExtension">

<Bundle Name="MyProgram" Version="1.0.0.1"
      Manufacturer="Test"
      UpgradeCode="GUID"
      SplashScreenSourceFile="Resources\splash.bmp"
      IconSourceFile="Resources\icon.ico">

<Update Location="http://test.laika42.com/UpdateInfo.xml"/>

<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id='ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost'>
  <PayloadGroupRef Id='VisualInstallerRuntimeFiles'/>
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>

<Variable Name="INSTALLFOLDER" bal:Overridable='yes' 
Value='[ProgramFilesFolder]Test\MyProgram\'/>

<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id='NetFx45Web' /> <!-- Fails to build without this? -->
  <MspPackage Id='PatchMsp' SourceFile='C:\Patches\Patch.msp' />
</Chain>
</Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem myself. It seems that the UpgradeCode for the bundle must be different to the UpgradeCode for the MSI - the bundle will remove anything older with the same Bundle UpgradeCode, including the original full MSI. I have to say I find the Wix documentation less than illuminating. Bdum-tsh.

The important bits seem to be having different UpgradeCodes for the MSI, the MSI bootstrapper bundle and the patch bootstrapper bundle but keeping each one of the three the same going forward, and the RelatedBundle element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <?include $(var.SolutionDir)\Installer\ProductDefs.wxi?>
  <?include $(var.SolutionDir)\Installer\version.wxi?>

  <!-- A DIFFERENT UpgradeCode to the main bundle, but consistent for all patches. I think. -->
  <?define PatchBundleUpgradeCode = "AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA"?>

  <!-- The UpgradeCode of the Bundle that was used to deploy the MSI originally. -->
  <?define MSIBundleUpgradeCode = "BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB"?>

  <!-- ... both of which are different to the MSI UpgradeCode. -->

  <Bundle Name="$(var.ProductName) $(var.ProductVersion)"
          ParentName="$(var.ProductName)"
          Version="$(var.ProductVersion)"
          Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)"
          UpgradeCode="$(var.PatchBundleUpgradeCode)"
          IconSourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)\Installer\MyIcon.ico"
          AboutUrl="https://www.somecompany.com/"
          HelpUrl="https://www.somecompany.com/support/"
          >
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
            LicenseFile="$(var.SolutionDir)\Bootstrapper\license.rtf"
            LogoFile="$(var.SolutionDir)\Bootstrapper\Logo.jpg"
            ShowVersion="yes"
            SuppressOptionsUI="yes"
            />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <OptionalUpdateRegistration Classification="Update" Name="$(var.ProductName) $(var.ProductVersion)"/>
    <RelatedBundle Id="$(var.MSIBundleUpgradeCode)" Action="Patch" />

    <Chain>
      <MspPackage SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)\Release\$(var.ProductName) $(var.ProductVersion) Patch.msp" DisplayInternalUI="yes"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Also, if you want to apply more than one minor patch, make sure your PatchMetadata element (in the patch.wxs, not the bundle.wxs) contains the following attribute otherwise the first patch will apply but subsequent ones won't.

```
MinorUpdateTargetRTM="1"
```