# Wix: Bootstraped .exe for msp can be installed when version is less than base application

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I have created a .exe that includes a msp that was created with wix

To start with I was having the issue that the patch exe would uninstall all of the application files, But I followed these instructions and got a patch exe that worked

[Wix: Creating Bootstrap .exe for .msp causes original version to uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867693/wix-creating-bootstrap-exe-for-msp-causes-original-version-to-uninstall)

I can now install this .exe to update my installed application

At the moment this results in a separate entry in add remove programs for the patch exe but it does update the base application files correctly.

The only issue I am having now is that I can install an older patch version than the main installed application

So for example, the base application is 5.1.2. It allows me to install a patch built for version 5.1.1. The patch will show up in add remove programs with the 5.1.1 version but thankfully it doesn't actually downgrade the main application.

Once a patch is installed it then wont let me install a lesser version patch.

As such I am concluding that the patch exe is only looking at the versions of any patches installed and not the main application that it is patching.

Does anyone know if this behaviour is by design?